# My Moto G (2014) stuck on a boot loop while plugged and now doesnt even boot to recovery while unplugged. Any solution?

Tags: boot-loop, motorola-moto-g, motorola

My Moto G (2014) Indian Version seems to have stuck on a boot loop. When I long press power button to on the phone the sequence of loop is phone vibrates, notification LED blinks for once and the 'Unlocked bootloader' screen appears (before unlocking it was motorola logo) and then screen goes black. This keeps on repeating. And the problem further is this only happens when the phone is plugged in, phone is inoperable when its unplugged.
Solutions I tried:

1. Flashing the stock ROM: Still the same boot loop
2. Performed factory by pressing the power button: Nothing
3. Tried booting in to Recovery mode, but after pressing the Volume Down button the same boot loop starts

I would again like to emphasize the fact that I tried this only when the phone was plugged. Nothing happens when the phone is unplugged. Must be the problem of faulty battery? And also I tried different chargers, no change. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is a manufacturing defect. I had the same issue with a Gen 1.
If its still under warranty you can get it replaced

Comment: Would you shed some light on what kind of "manufacturing defect" it is? There must be some info about it.